# Logical bitwise operators

Tags: c++

I want to set the **second bit** to zero for ex: 18 in decimal( 10010 in binaray) so
I wrote this code below. in the  first instance it prints 0 for the second instance it prints 16 which is the correct one. why is that happening to me the logic in the code is the same but it prints diffrent results. can someone clear that up to me.

```
 int main()
    { 
        int a = 18;
        a = a&(0 << 1); // first instance
        cout << a << endl; // a = 0
        a = 18;
        a = a&(~(1 << 1)); // second
        cout << a << endl; // a = 16
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: How is  "the logic the same"? Explain your thinking.

Comment: well at least i think it does something like this
10010 
      0   and
the result should be
10000
@latedeveloper

Comment: I meant "why do you think (0 << 1) and (~(1 << 1)) do the same thing.

Comment: i guessed it shifts zero one bit and "logical and" with the number.
second instance i thought it shifts 1 one bit and "logical or" and the "logical not" which is also zero. then logical"and" it with the number. sorry if the answer is confusing.@latedeveloper

Comment: The ~ operator is bitwise XOR, not OR.

Comment: it is bitwise not ~ i think.
this is ^ xor @latedeveloper

Comment: Sorry, I meant NOT - fingers not doing what brain told them to. In any case, it's not an OR.

Comment: yup , it is not i knew i said something wrong. @latedeveloper

Comment: This isn't the problem, but don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Comment: so, they are different! gotta check it up, thank you. @PeteBecker

Answer (score 5, accepted):

a is 18

```
a = 10010
```

First

```
a & (0 << 1)
10010 & (00000 << 1) // move 0 one bit left
10010 & 00000 = 00000  = 0
```

Second

```
a & (~(1 << 1))
10010 & ( ~(00001 <<  1))  // move 1 one bit left
10010 & ( ~(00010)) // reverse 2
10010 & 11101
10010 & 11101 = 10000 = 16
```

Answer (score 1):

The logic is not the same.

`(0 << 1)` means shift left `0` one bit, which leads to `0`. Bitwise and with 0 always returns zero.

`(1 << 1)` means shift left `1` one bit, which leads to `2`.